# Expression must have class type when overloading array index operator

Tags: c++

The code is below

The error is "Expression must have class type" on the line:
`if (index >= mElements.size())`

But not on the line `return mElements[index]`

I dont understand why, is this a glitch?

```
struct Matrix4x4
{
    float mElements[16];

    Matrix4x4()
    {
        memset(&this->mElements, 0, sizeof(this->mElements));
        this->mElements[0] = 1;
        this->mElements[5] = 1;
        this->mElements[10] = 1;
        this->mElements[15] = 1;
    }

    Matrix4x4(const float (&mElements)[16])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            this->mElements[i] = mElements[i];
    }

    float& operator[](int index)
    {
        if (index >= mElements.size()) {
            printf("Array index out of bound, exiting");
            return 0.0F;
        }
        return mElements[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do `mElements.size()` in C++.  plain arrays don't have any functions.

Comment: Alternative: use [`std::array<float, 16> mElements;`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) as your member, and adjust accordingly.

Comment: can't you do sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])? It will gets you the length try once

Comment: @SyedMohibUddin I think that this is not the best way to get an array length, due that there's a standard array instantiation on the STL, but it solves the problem in many cases

Comment: Yeah there are many ways one is pointer hack *(&arr + 1) - arr

Answer (score 2):

Plain arrays don't have `.size()`. Use `std::size(mElements)` from `#include <iterator>`, or `std::extent_v<decltype(mElements)>` from `#include <type_traits>`.

Answer (score 0):

`mElements` is a plain old array. They don't have member functions. Hence, `mElements.size()` is not accepted by the compiler.

With the introduction of `std::array` in C++11, there is less of a need to use plain arrays.

Replace

```
float mElements[16];
```

with

```
std::array<float, 16> mElements;
```

Then, you can use `mElements.size()`.